# Read entries bibtex (Parser bibtext entries)

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, bibtex, biblatex

I need to read a bibtext file, but i dont know to read it. My idea is read all entries for a txt or bib file and create object related to the entries.
I've tried to use the Renanbr bibtext-parser (https://packagist.hotlibs.com/renanbr/bibtex-parser/package)  but I can not get it to work. I can't 
install correctly the Packagist renanbr. I pasted the:
 "require": {
renanbr/bibtex-parser: "*",
}
In my installed.json file, this is inside of my composer binder. But didn't work. After, I copied the composer.json from this url (https://github.com/renanbr/bibtex-parser/blob/master/composer.json) and pasted again inside of my installed json but i cant get it to work. I don't know to use the composer. Some idea or help for read bibtext entries please?

I use Symfony2 (Version 2.7.9) and PHP 5.6.15

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have composer installed :

- Linux: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx
- Windows: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

For adding `renanbr/bibtex-parser` as a dependency you should run the composer command inside your project folder :

```
composer require renanbr/bibtex-parser ^2
```

Some references :

- https://github.com/renanbr/bibtex-parser#installing
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require